# How do I set request parameter in Spring interceptor?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

The goal is to set request parameter in `HttpServletRequest` request.

I saw that this goal can be achieved by using a servlet filter plus `HttpServletRequestWrapper`.

The question is how can I achieve the same result with Spring interceptor (I mean by implementing `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`) ?

Comment: You cannot, you can only do this in a filter. Also why would you need to add request parameters?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Anyway, I decided to use another approach.